# Can't allow an anonymous access on my resource server

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

I have two servers: authorization and resource, it works perfect if I am using `Bearer access_token` for my resource server but I need to have an anonymous access to some endpoints (i.e. `http://localhost:8080/games` but not `http://localhost:8080/games/new`). How to make it?
Now I'm trying to allow an anonymous access to all endpoints for test but it doesn't work. Below my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "virto";

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
        resources.tokenServices(tokenService());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.anonymous()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public RemoteTokenServices tokenService() {
        final String url = ServerConfig.USERS_HOST + "/oauth/check_token";
        RemoteTokenServices tokenService = new RemoteTokenServices();
        tokenService.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl(url);
        tokenService.setClientId("virto");
        tokenService.setClientSecret("secret");

        return tokenService;
    }
}
```

And my `Application` class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableKafka
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication
                .run(Application.class, args);
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = (DispatcherServlet)ctx
                .getBean("dispatcherServlet");
        dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
    }
}
```

Now if I'm trying to get an access to some endpoint without access token I'm getting the next message in the browser:

```
<oauth>
    <error_description>
        Full authentication is required to access this resource
    </error_description>
    <error>unauthorized</error>
</oauth>
```

Comment: Where do you specify /games/new as anoymous() access in the config?